# C# WPF: Fire SelectionChanged Event First Before others Events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, listbox, listboxitem

My question is simple:
 
I have a listBox contains some `DataTemplate`.
 As you see I have the `SelectionChanged` event inside the listbox:

```
SelectionChanged = "stationListBox_SelectionChanged"
```

and the mouseDown event inside the grid (the grid is part of the data template):

```
MouseDown = "Grid_MouseDown"
```

I want the `SelectionChanged` event to **get fired first** and then the `MouseDown` event.
   That because i want to do something on the selected item so i need to know first who i chose.

the XML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="stationListBox" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="stationListBox_SelectionChanged" Background="#FF5C7591"                             
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:StationViewModel}">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" >
            <Frame BorderBrush="#B935373F" BorderThickness="4"></Frame>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10" >                
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="30" Height="30" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\station.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Left" Width="80" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\turnOn.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding IsStationOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\turnOff.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding IsStationClose, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                               </Grid>
                        <Image Width="20" Height="20" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\delete2.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"
                            ToolTip="Delete station" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" />
                    </StackPanel>                
                    <StackPanel Name="_editStationGrid" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding IsEditable,Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <Expander Visibility="Visible" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpandered, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock>Edit Station:</TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,5,5,5" >
                                    <Label Content="Name:"/>
                                    <TextBox MinWidth="120" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0,5,0" >
                                    <Label Content="IP:" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                    <TextBox MinWidth="120" Text="{Binding IP, Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

the code:

```
private void stationListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this._selectedStation = ((StationViewModel)this.stationListBox.SelectedItem);
}

private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (inEditMode && e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        if (_selectedStation.IsSelected == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
            _selectedStation.IsSelected = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            _selectedStation.IsSelected = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    if (!inEditMode && e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        if (_selectedStation_Event != null)
            _selectedStation_Event(_selectedStation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do that something in SelectionChanged event handler?

Comment: because i need to observe if there was one click on the item or double click and for that i need the mouseEventArgs object (e.Clicks property). I need that first the selection will change and than after the mouseDown event fire.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Dispatcher object:

```
    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        ));
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't help me cause i nedd to know first who the selected ite, to do the thing on that item.

Comment: Did you try it?  Using the dispatcher will use the event queue to defer processing of the respective handler.  The SelectedChanged event will then occur first.  See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824.aspx)

Comment: hi, the solution you gave me helped me Partially, cause when it enter the mouseDown method and to the BeginInvoke and than after enter the SelectionChange method but after this, it come back agine to selctionChange method and in this time the selected item, is null;